# Сортировка массива merge

Tags: java, сортировка, merge

Хотел спросить, как мне написать реализацию методом слияния для определенного количества элементов, т.е не весь введенный массив, а только 2-8 допустим. Пытаюсь добавить в новый массив `arr2` полученные элементы, но вылезает ошибка:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 6 out of bounds for length 6`

Может кто подсказать почему не получается? Элементов при слиянии должно же быть 6? Почему он ругается что пытаюсь больше внести элементов?

```java
public class SortMerge {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] A = {5,2,4,6,1,3,2,6};
        sort(A, 2, A.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(A[i]);
        }
    }


    public static void sort(int[] A, int p, int r) {
        if (p <r) {
            int q = (r - p) / 2;
            int[] leftHalf = new int[q];
            int[] rightHalf = new int[r - q];

            for(int i = p; i < q; i++) {
                leftHalf[i] = A[i];
            }

            for(int i = q; i < r; i++) {
                rightHalf[i-q] = A[i];
            }

            merge(leftHalf,rightHalf, r, p);
        }
    }

    public static void merge(int[] leftHalf, int[] rightHalf, int r, int p) {
        int[] arr2 = new int[r-p];

        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

        while(i < leftHalf.length && j < rightHalf.length) {
            if (leftHalf[i] <= rightHalf[j]) {
                arr2[k] = leftHalf[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                arr2[k] = rightHalf[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        while (i < leftHalf.length) {
            arr2[k] = leftHalf[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }

        while (j < rightHalf.length) {
            arr2[k] = rightHalf[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+index+out+of+bounds

Comment: 1. Код не компилируется - метод `merge` вызывается с лишним параметром `q`.  2. Массив `A` не сортируется, так как создаются локальные массивы, в них что-то копируется и производятся какие-то манипуляции, но все эти изменения теряются при выходе из методов.

Comment: Не понял где вызывается q в методе merge? 
А мне надо отсортировать не массив A, а новый массив с меньшим количеством элементов. Т.е метод merge надо сделать не void а int[]?